# how can I get near rows near one specific row in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to get the near rows given one specific row. For example
give two dataframes:

```
User time
B    2
A    3

User time
A   1
B   2
A   3
D   6
E   7
G   10
D   11
```

The first one is the specific rows, and the sencond one is the whole table, let us set near window size as 1. Hence, the result show be the following:

```
User time
A   1
B   2
A   3

User time
B   2
A   3
D   6
```

but how can I get this? Thanks..

Comment: The problem with your example is that dataframes aren't [ordered](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207) and that the result can differ as long as you don't provide a column which allows ordering (e.g. row number).

Comment: The table is ordered by time

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Actually it is easy. If anyone meets this problem , please utilize rowsBetween and window functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lead/lag over a window. For this your dataframe needs to be ordered. let's assume you have another column "X".

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import Window, lag, lead
df.withColumn("c_1", lead("time").over(Window(partitionBy("user").orderBy("X"))))
```